# how to run ethercat delta servo with ros

Tags: ros, servo, ethercat

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to configure the ethercat servo drive with ros to control the position of servo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270137/how-to-run-ethercat-delta-servo-with-ros/) by [Tomn](https://answers.ros.org/users/31775/tomn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see some earlier Q&A's, such as #q226843 and #q199494.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0